# Ajax alert - How to add 'don't remind again button'?

Tags: ajax, json

I am new to Ajax.

I have an alert when a page is loaded which shows the user a note for a specific user. When the profile of this user is viewed the alert containing the note will appear.

What i would like is for the user to have a tick button on this alert which says dont remind again? This checkbox would ideally call a function to set column 'read' to 1, so next time the users profile is displayed it will not show the alert?

Hope i explained correctly.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.aspx/GetMembersNotes",
            data: '{' +
                    'nameID:"' + $('#nameID').val() + '",' +
                    'addrID:"' + $('#addrID').val() + '"' +
                   '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                var data = json_parse(msg.d);

                if (!data.error) {
                    $.each(data, function(d) {
                    if (data[d].read = 1){
                        alert(data[d].notes);
                    }                   
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert("Cannot get memeber's notes data\n" + data.error);
                }
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                alert('Get Memeber\'s Notes Failure' + msg);
            }
        });`
```

The above shows the alert. In the GetMemberNotes function a JSON string is built and returns notes and read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot modify an `alert()` box. It is native stuff. You cannot put any controls on it and cannot modify its behavior. The only thing you can do is put plain text on it. You might use a [`confirm()`](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptconfirm.php) box (it gives a Yes/No functionality), but it is not perfect.

You can try building your own dialog, or use [jQuery UI's Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) for the most flexible results.